# Getting number of users depending on their age

Tags: search, grep, awk

I have a text file in which there are two columns:

```
Name  Age
Ashko 32
Mohan 45
arun  21
```

I want to get the number of users whose age is greater than 25 ex 2 in above case

Comment: I think this question is not appropriate here, one that you are not clear if you want it done in bash script, php, java, python or perl? second this is not the platform for programming question and someone is downvoting your question, better clarify and edit the question and move it to appropriate forum. Here is a test script that will help you with a bash script. 

`echo "Enter Age";

read age;

echo "Age=$age";

if [ $age \> 25 ];

then 

echo "Age is greater than 25";

else 

echo "Age is less than 25";

fi;`

Put it in a text file and save it as test.sh, use chmod +x to make it executable.

Comment: I now see you have used tags for grep and awk to clarify the intent, you want to search for line in a text file that has a number greater than 25 and perhaps list it out, you may want to edit the question.

Comment: You edited your question to add some sample data - which is good. However you still haven't demonstrated any effort to solve the problem yourself: remember this site doesn't exist to do your assignments (whether school or work) for you, but to serve as a repository of good answers to *useful* questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
grep -E "2[5-9]|[3-9][0-9]\b" user
```

where `user` is the filename you store the name and age.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk '{if($2>25) {print $1}}' your_input_file
```

*Example*

```
$ cat foo
Name Age
Ashko 32
Mohan 45
arun 21

$ awk '{if($2>25) {print $1}}' foo
Ashko
Mohan
```